# Can't update Craft 3, permissions issue

Tags: manual-updates

Upon running the update tool in the Craft CMS, I get this error.

***Error: file_put_contents(path/to/file/composer.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied***

What permissions are causing this error? Is it simply the case of changing the perms on the composer.json file? If so, what should they be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the required Craft 3 file permissions: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/installation.html#step-2-set-the-file-permissions